# How to make Tern autocomplete CreateJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs, tern

I'm trying to make [Tern](http://ternjs.net) to work with [CreateJS](http://www.createjs.com) library.
The library is huge so Tern runs out of time if I try to read it.
Tern supports JSON type definitions for this, but if I compile it with condense utility it throws error on trying to read resulting json.
I can't find any compiled json too.